# Xcode: Dark mode doesn't work if the color is in the framework

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, frameworks, ios-darkmode

On xcode I work within a workspace where there is a basic project and a framework. All colors are defined within the framework. When I configure a label with the color assets of the framework from the basic project on storyboard, the color is taken correctly, but if I then switch to dark mode, the color does not change, it always remains the same.

[image: Configuration color label in project]

setting textColorBlack in dark mode should appear white but it doesn't work.

[image: textColorBlack in framework project]

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please remove any. only dark and light select. please try it

Comment: I tried to remove it, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Xib/Storyboard just preserves selected color name (visible at dev time from all spaces), but in run-time on color schema changes it cannot find it, because by default it searches by name in main bundle.

Instead we have to assign color programmatically specifying exact location of color, like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.textColor = UIColor(named: "myColor", 
          in: Bundle(identifier: "framework_identifier") ?? .main,  // << here !!
          compatibleWith: .current)
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: I'd go so far and call it bug in storyboard code. Named colors in swift packages work otherwise. The light/dark version works, when viewed in Interface Builder and then you start the app and pull your hair out. :-( Thanks anyway for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In our case we defined some extensions, that load the corresponding Colors from the asset catalog:

```swift
public extension Color {
    public enum Primary {
        static let green = Color("PrimaryGreen", bundle: .module)
    }
}
public extension UIColor {
    public enum Primary {
        static let green = UIColor(Color.Primary.green)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI's `Color` is loaded directly from the asset catalog, but UIKit's `UIColor` is instantiated from the loaded `Color`. This causes the described problem, since the `UIColor` won't automatically update, when switching to dark mode. The solution, of course, is to also load the `UIColor` directly from the asset catalog .

Comment: Thanks, this worked for us, so the bounty is yours. I do not know if it also works for the original poster.